# iTunes ask for old Apple ID and Email

Tags: iphone, itunes, email, apple-id

about a year ago i had to change my email because my old one got hacked. i changes my apple id to fit my new email and deleted my old one. the old email i used does no longer excist as i deleted that one too, but everytime i try to update my apps, itunes ask me to log in to my old Apple ID with my old email saying "sign in to itunes store. enter the password for your apple ID (old email)? i have made sure my new email is registered on my phone and it is the email that is used in app store, it is also the one displayed in the settings.
how can i fix this????